# Navegação entre paginas (Android)

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin-forms

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;

namespace ValModas
{
    [Activity(Label = "ValModas", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }

        private async void Button_OnClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageFem());
        }
    }
}
```

Estou tentando fazer com que chame outra pagina, como posso fazer?

Comment: o que tá acontecendo quando você chama o Navigation.PushAsync ?

Comment: Encontrei uma solução usando o "Intent", obrigado

Answer (score 1):

```
private void BtnAcessorios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var LoginAces = new Intent(this, typeof(AcesActivity));
        StartActivity(LoginAces);
    }
```

> Essa foi a solução que eu encontrei para esse problema